# Resize image and maintain its aspect ratio in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to select an image from photo library, this is the photo [image] which I have downloaded from net and is stored in my photo lib.

So now I want to give user an option to select an image from photo lib and apply as a backgroundImage throught my app, but when I do it, I get the image this way on my iphone screen

[image]

Actually the image has been filled the screen, because the content mode specified is "scaleToFill".

1) I want to know how to make this image maintain its aspect ratio and also fill the screen?

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Aspectfit can be used

Comment: are you using storyboard for that?

Answer (score 2):

check [this blog](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/). use these two files

[UIImage+Resize.h](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.h)

[UIImage+Resize.m](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.m)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage-900x675"]; // SomeImage-900x675.png 
CGFloat targetWidth = 320.0;
CGFloat scaleFactor = targetWidth / image.size.width; 
CGFloat targetHeight = image.size.height * scaleFactor; 
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetWidth, targetHeight);
UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImage:targetSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
```

Answer (score 0):

though your image is taking all the screen size, Your image size is biger...You will try by scaling image with following resolutions
320*480, 
640*960,
1240*2208

Comment: But after scaling does it render properly?